# Performance slick query one to many

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0, playframework-2.5

I'm using play 2.5 and slick 3.1.1 and I'm trying to build optimal query for multiple relations one to many, and one to one. I have a such db model:

```
case class Accommodation(id: Option[Long], landlordId: Long, name: String)
case class LandLord(id: Option[Long], name: String)
case class Address(id: Option[Long], accommodationId: Long, street: String)
case class ExtraCharge(id: Option[Long], accommodationId: Long, title: String)
```

For data output:

```
case class AccommodationFull(accommodation: Accommodation, landLord: LandLord, extraCharges:Seq[ExtraCharge], addresses:Seq[Address])
```

I've created two queries to get accommodation by id:

```
/** Retrieve a accommodation from the id. */
def findByIdFullMultipleQueries(id: Long): Future[Option[AccommodationFull]] = {
  val q = for {
    (a, l) <- accommodations join landLords on (_.landlordId === _.id)
    if a.id === id
  } yield (a, l)

  for {
    (data) <- db.run(q.result.headOption)
    (ex) <- db.run(extraCharges.filter(_.accommodationId === id).result)
    (add) <- db.run(addresses.filter(_.accommodationId === id).result)
  } yield data.map { accLord => AccommodationFull(accLord._1, accLord._2, ex, add) }
}

/** Retrieve a accommodation from the id. */
def findByIdFull(id: Long): Future[Option[AccommodationFull]] = {

  val qr = accommodations.filter(_.id === id).join(landLords).on(_.landlordId === _.id)
    .joinLeft(extraCharges).on(_._1.id === _.accommodationId)
    .joinLeft(addresses).on(_._1._1.id === _.accommodationId)
      .result.map { res =>
    res.groupBy(_._1._1._1.id).headOption.map {

       case (k, v) =>
         val addresses = v.flatMap(_._2).distinct
         val extraCharges = v.flatMap(_._1._2).distinct
         val landLord = v.map(_._1._1._2).head
         val accommodation = v.map(_._1._1._1).head
         AccommodationFull(accommodation, landLord, extraCharges, addresses)
    }
  }

  db.run(qr)
}
```

After tests multiple query is like 5x faster than join. How can I create more optimal join query?

**=== Update ===**

I'm testing now on postgresql 9.3 with data:

```
private[bootstrap] object InitialData {

  def landLords = (1L to 10000L).map { id =>
    LandLord(Some(id), s"Good LandLord $id")
  }

  def accommodations = (1L to 10000L).map { id =>
    Accommodation(Some(id), s"Nice house $id", 100 * id, 3, 5, 500, 1l, None)
  }

  def extraCharge = (1L to 10000L).flatMap { id =>
    (1 to 100).map { nr =>
      ExtraCharge(None, id, s"Extra $nr", 100.0)
    }
  }

  def addresses = (1L to 1000L).flatMap { id =>
    (1 to 100).map {  nr =>
      Address(None, id, s"Słoneczna 4 - $nr", "17-200", "", "PL")
    }
  }
}
```

and here results for multiple runs (ms):

```
JOIN: 367
MULTI: 146
JOIN: 306
MULTI: 110
JOIN: 300
MULTI: 103
```

**== Update 2 ==**

After adding indexes it's better, but still multi is much faster:

```
def accommodationLandLordIdIndex = index("ACCOMMODATION__LANDLORD_ID__INDEX", landlordId, unique = false)
def addressAccommodationIdIndex = index("ADDRESS__ACCOMMODATION_ID__INDEX", accommodationId, unique = false)
def extraChargeAccommodationIdIndex = index("EXTRA_CHARGE__ACCOMMODATION_ID__INDEX", accommodationId, unique = false)
```

I made a test:

```
val multiResult = (1 to 1000).map { i =>
  val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
  Await.result(accommodationDao.findByIdFullMultipleQueries(i), Duration.Inf)
  System.currentTimeMillis() - start
}
println(s"MULTI AVG Result: ${multiResult.sum.toDouble / multiResult.length}")

val joinResult = (1 to 1000).map { i =>
  val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
  Await.result(accommodationDao.findByIdFull(i), Duration.Inf)
  System.currentTimeMillis() - start
}
println(s"JOIN AVG Result: ${joinResult.sum.toDouble / joinResult.length}")
```

here result for 2 runs:

```
MULTI AVG Result: 3.287
JOIN AVG Result: 96.797
MULTI AVG Result: 3.206
JOIN AVG Result: 100.221
```

Comment: We need more details. What's the database you are using? Turn on the slick debug logs to see the constructed query and try running it against the database. This will give you more hints about what could be wrong.

Comment: I'm using just for testing H2 database, I will try postgresql

Answer (score 2):

[Postgres does not add indexes for foreign key columns](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK). The multi-query is using an index on all three tables (the primary key), while the single join query will scan the join tables for the desired IDs.

Try adding indexes on your `accommodationId` columns.

**Update**

While indexes would help if this were a 1:1 relationship, it looks like these are all 1:many relationships. In that case, using joins and a later `distinct` filter is going to return a lot more data from the database than you need.

For your data model, doing multiple queries looks like the correct way to process the data.

Comment: after adding test with multiple id's 1 -> 1000 now multi is 30x time faster

Comment: I updated my answer; I think doing multiple queries in correct in your case.

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on your DB engine. Slick generates queries that may not be optimal (see [docs](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.1.1/)), but you need to profile queries on a database level to understand what's happening and to optimize

Comment: I've added test for postgresql

Comment: I think getting one to many relation it's quite standard procedure, so how can I do it in postgresql (probably the most popular db), or how would you do it on another db?